# How to identify request (by ID) through middleware chain in Express.

Tags: node.js, logging, express

I am developping a RESTful server in node.js, using Express as framework, and Winston, for the moment, as logger module. 
This server will handle a big amount of simultaneous request, and it would be very useful to me to be able to track the log entries for each specific request, using something like a 'request ID'. The straight solution is just to add this ID as another piece of logging information each time I want to make a log entry, but it will mean to pass the 'request ID' to each method used by the server.

I would like to know if there is any node.js/javascript module or technique that would allow me to do this in an easier way, without carrying around the request ID for each specific request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `req` object that does comes with every request in express.
So the first route you would do in your application would be:

```
var logIdIterator = 0;

app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  req.log = {
    id: ++logIdIterator
  }
  return next();
});
```

And then anywhere within express, you can access that `id` in `req` object: `req.log.id`;
You will still need to pass some data into functions that do want to create some logs. In fact you might have logging function within `req.log` object, so that way it will be guaranteed that logging will happen only when there is access to `req.log` object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also though to use the solution you propose. However, I had in mind to automatically identify the ID to be applied. A solution I implemented was to store the ID in the request object, and when calling my custom log function, it would look for the ID up in the callstack. I know this is wrong by several reasons (accessing the parameter information of other functions is forbidden in "strict mode", not efficient, and getting a new stack when a I/O event is fired).

I guess it is just not possible and the solution you proposed seems it's the one that fits best.

Answer (score 17):

If you auto-increment, your later log analytics won't be able to uniquely identify requests, because different instances will generate colliding IDs, and restarting the app will automatically cause ID collisions.

Here's another possible solution.

Install cuid:

```
npm install --save cuid
```

Then in your main app file:

```
var cuid = require('cuid');
var requestId = function requestId(req, res, next) {
  req.requestId = cuid();
  next();
};

// Then, at the top of your middleware:
app.use(requestId);
```

Now you'll get a friendly request ID that is unlikely to collide, and you'll be able to uniquely identify your requests for your log analytics and debugging, even across multiple instances, and server restarts.

Comment: Yeah, this certainly better solution, but the problem with this is how you expose the id in winston logs so that you dont make much data duplication.

Comment: I would also use domains (or whatever they decide to replace domains with) so you are not polluting function calls by passing request information down throughout the layers of your code.

Comment: Domains have been deprecated, and there are no concrete plans for a replacement.

Comment: Check out [Continuation Local Storage](https://github.com/othiym23/node-continuation-local-storage) for passing these kind of values along the call chain

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling search for a solution for this problem. 
The thing I didn't like it about solutions suggested here was that they imply to share the req object among all the functions along the project.
I found out a solution mixing your approach (creating an uuid per request) and with a library (continuation-local-storage) that allows sharing namespaces among modules.

You can find the explanation in this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47261545/5710581

If you want more info, I wrote down all these ideas and all the code in a post, in order to explain everything in one place:
[Express.js: Logging info with global unique request ID – Node.js](https://solidgeargroup.com/express-logging-global-unique-request-identificator-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using Global Variables.

What I like to do is to populate a META object before each request.

I use a UUID generator (https://github.com/kelektiv/node-uuid) to ID a request

Here's an example

```
  app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    req.meta = {
      ip: req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress,
      timestamp: uuid(),
      user_agent: req.headers['user-agent'],
      body: req.body,
    }
    return next();
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @moka , Using the request ID in each request is the crux of solving the problem. Another way of abstracting all these is by making use of **http-context** and **uuid**

So set a UUID in the httpContext before all your middlewares (set as an application middleware and not as a router middlware). now you can get the uuid anywhere in your code and log it.

Here is a sample implementation I have used

You can get the complete reference here [uuid in request](https://solidgeargroup.com/express-logging-global-unique-request-identificator-nodejs)

```
const uuid = require('node-uuid');
const httpContext = require('express-http-context');
....
 this.expressApp.use(httpContext.middleware);
        this.expressApp.use((req, res, next) => {
            httpContext.set('reqId', uuid.v4());
            next();
        });
```

Now I have used the reqId set here in my custom pino logger'

```
public infoLogService (fileName): pino.Logger {
        return pino({
            level: 'info',
            name: this.appService.getApp_name(),    

            messageKey: 'XXX-Logs',
            base: {pid: process.pid, hostname: os.hostname,
                timestamp: this.getTimeStamp(),
                appName: this.appService.getApp_name(),
                fileName: fileName,
                request_id: **isNullOrUndefined(httpContext.get('reqId'))** ? 'Not an actual request ' : httpContext.get('reqId')
            },
            enabled: true,
            useLevelLabels: true,


        });
    }
```

If the reqId is null it means that the loggers have been inserted in code that is used before starting the express App. Hope you can use this as an alternate solution