# node.js express request Id

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to create some sort of a request Id for logging purposes which will be available to me through every function in the request flow. I want to log every step of the request flow with an Id stating which log line is for which request.

I've looked over some ideas and ran into 2 main suggestions:

The first is creating a middleware that will add a field in the 'req' object like so(as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17701796/how-to-identify-request-by-id-through-middleware-chain-in-express)):

```
var logIdIterator = 0;

app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  req.log = {
    id: ++logIdIterator
  }
  return next();
});
```

And the second is using [continuation-local-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/continuation-local-storage)

The problems are:

For the first approach - it means I'll have to pass an extra argument to each function in the flow and this is not an easy solution to do over a mature application with countless APIs and flows.

The second one looks promising but unfortunately it has some issues where the state gets lost(see [here](https://github.com/othiym23/node-continuation-local-storage/issues/29) for example). 
Also, it happened a few times when we used our redis library - which is bad because redis requests happen on each of our flows.

I guess if I don't find another solution, I'll have to use the first approach, it's just that I want to avoid passing an extra parameter to thousands of existing functions.

My question is - how do you suggest to maintain a request Id through the request flow?

Comment: Why would passing around the `req` object with just one more property in it (which is just a number) be a problem? I don't think it'll result in any noticeable performance hit?

Comment: It's not the performance I'm worried about. adding an extra parameter to a large amount of functions is time-consuming and bug-prone

Comment: Why would you need to add an extra parameter for this to be implemented?

Comment: Because our internal functions don't get the 'req' parameter so for them to get the 'req' object or even just the 'requestId', an extra parameter will need to be added

Comment: I will leave this as a comment as it doesn't apply to Express. But for the record, [HapiJS takes care of this](https://hapijs.com/api#request-properties) for you. It has a unique `request.id` that works extremely well for logging like this. And I would recommend it for production applications.

Comment: @SethHolladay thanks for the response. it seems like this id is a field the request object, but in order to use it in the whole flow of the API you must pass it as an argument to all functions within the flow, correct? if so, it isn't much different from the express solution

Comment: @GiladBison in Express this is indeed a problem, where apps tend to be complex flows of functions that forward state across many boundaries. In practice Hapi avoids this, as the architecture encourages a highly organized application structure with isolated components. The request object is usually available without passing it around a lot. Check out the API. Put what you can into a plugin using [server.handler()](https://hapijs.com/api#serverhandlername-method) or the various [extension points](https://hapijs.com/api#request-lifecycle).

Comment: Happened upon this thread when looking for a better alternative to approach #1. Haven't found one either. How did you end up solving this?

Comment: I havn't found a good solution, so I just passed the parameter to some main functions and logged only from these functions.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-request-id

This is the middleware that will append uuid for every request

```js
var app = require('express')();
var addRequestId = require('express-request-id')();
 
app.use(addRequestId);
 
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.send(req.id);
    next();
});
 
app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
 
// curl localhost:3000 
// d7c32387-3feb-452b-8df1-2d8338b3ea22
```

Answer (score 2):

For node >= 16, You can use [AsyncLocalStorage](https://nodejs.org/api/async_context.html#class-asynclocalstorage) provided by nodejs.
From nodejs docs

> These classes are used to associate state and propagate it throughout callbacks and promise chains. They allow storing data throughout the lifetime of a web request or any other asynchronous duration. It is similar to thread-local storage in other languages

You need to create an `asyncLocalStorage` instance and export that. This same instace should be used in all files.

```
//asyncLocalStorage.js
const { AsyncLocalStorage } = require('node:async_hooks');

const asyncLocalStorage = new AsyncLocalStorage();

moduel.exports = asyncLocalStorage;
```

Then you can use a middleware to create requestId and associate that state to that particular request.

```
//middleware.js
const crypto = require('crypto');
const asyncLocalStorage = require('./asyncLocalStorage.js);

function createRequestId(req, res, next) {
  asyncLocalStorage.run(crypto.randomUUID, () => {
    next()
  }
}

module.exports = createRequestId
```

We are calling `next()` from inside `asyncLocalStorage.run()` so that entire request gets excetuted from inside that function and we can access requestId in all the functions that gets called in that request lifetime.

```
//service.js
const asyncLocalStorage = require('./asyncLocalStorage.js')
const testfunction() {
  const requestId = asyncLocalStorage.getStore();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have asynchronous communications, and you want to preserve context without either a) closures or b) parameter passing. I'm afraid that your best bet is to pass *something* to all the functions which need to know it - whether it be the `req` object, a request id, a curried `log` function call - something.

Whatever you pass can be easily enough refactored into any of the others - a plain id could look up an object from global storage (not *good*, but *possible*) for example. With that in mind - you *might* already have *something* being passed around to the methods which uniquely identifies the request; in which case, using that as a key and looking up additional data from a global storage (ie, `require` a file with an `module.exports.cache = new Map();` or something, no reason to pollute the global namespace).

As you've noticed, attempts to do wonky things with the language are often brittle (especially when meeting other wonky things). That said, you could figure out how `continuation-local-storage` works internally, debug it along with your breaking libraries, and use it or a homebrew solution.

You sound uncomfortable with the cost of maintaining this code. This is a code smell - and adding implicit global continuation local state sounds like something that will only make understanding and maintaining the code *harder* moving forward instead of *simpler*. You might take this as a learning opportunity, and ask *why* you need the request id, and *why* it wasn't needed when whomever wrote the code. I'm sorry that without knowing the codebase itself, this is the best answer I can give.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your original routine a little more sophisticated by (a) storing the information as a server-only cookie and (b) putting more information into the cookie beyond just a counter. For example, I use the following as trace of all calls to my app:

```
console.log('['+count+'] at: '+format.asString('hh:mm:ss.SSS', new Date())+' Url is: ' + req.url);
```

where 'count' is incremented from app start (yes, better to use a persistent singleton). This gives me every call to the server (req.url) and exactly when that call was made. This could easily be extended to pick up the sessionID, if your app is doing session level management.

Comment: I don't quite understand this solution.
Let's say I just started the application - so counter is 0, and then I have 3 simultaneous requests handled in the server. counter will now be set to 3 - meaning that if I want to log the entire flow of the function I will get 3 for all the requests which isn't helping me to differentiate them.
Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express and wanted to import the [express-request-id](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-request-id) instead of the required approach. You may try this.

```
import expressRequestId from 'express-request-id'
import express from 'express'

const framework = express()
framework.use(expressRequestId())
```

Every function would come with a unique ID. Just access it like this (req.id)